# Which Data Structure should I use for a Map? (C++)

Tags: c++, dictionary, graph, structure, maze

I'm currently working on a Simulation with autonomous agents and I'm trying to implement a wayfinding algorithm. In my program there are Rooms which are connected to each other. Each agent should have his own limited map of the system and expand it by wandering through the rooms and adding them to the map. If they get a task to go to a specific room which is in their map they should get a vector with the best route from their current location to the destination. I'm still on beginners level and the only data structures I used so far are vectors and structs. Could someone point me into the right direction?

Comment: What about [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=map)?

Comment: Or [`unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

Comment: I think this is a graph problem. C++ STL doesn't contain any structures representing graphs, you can look at boost graph library. Or maybe 2D incidence matrix,list of neighbours might do.

Comment: i thought about std::map, but in this each key can have only one value. and rooms can have several connections

Comment: A `std::vector` doesn't sound like a bad solution.

Comment: This is a graph problem, not a stl map issue.  k_vh: how many rooms can a room be connected to?

Comment: @k_vh Sounds like you want a `std::multimap` then.

Comment: @EvilTeach there is only a minimum of 1, theoretically it could be connected to hundreds of rooms

Comment: as your rooms seem to be aligned on a 2d grid, i'd use a plain `std::vector` with some 2d index accessing and put all conections etc in the elements the vector is holding

Comment: @k_vh.  How do you expect to initialize the rooms and all of the connections?

Comment: The two standard structures for representing graphs are an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) and an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).  There is no graph container in the standard library, so you will have to build it yourself (or use something like [boost.graph](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html), which may be overkill in your case.)

Comment: @EvilTeach the rooms get initialized through an overarching system class which handles everything room related

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create a Room class that contains a vector that holds a subscript to the rooms that it is connected to.

You system class could then hold a vector of Rooms that are subscriptable.

Your agents could have their own vector of Rooms that they populate while they travel, or a vector of subscript of the rooms that they have visited.

Comment: but how could I create a route of rooms that goes from one to another room which aren't directly connected?

Comment: @k_vh If your rooms are in Euclidean space, [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).